# Force eject a CD from a broken iMac SuperDrive (hardware issue)

Tags: imac, hardware, optical-drive, dvd

Today, I inserted a CD into my 2007 iMac desktop, but when I tried to eject the CD, the optical drive made some odd whirring noises, and nothing was ejected. After further research, I tried every kind of software solution available, from Disk Utility to typing `drutil eject` in Terminal to restarting while holding the mouse button, but I am convinced this is a hardware issue.

There aren't any Apple-certified technicians near me. Is there a way I will be able to eject the disc from my computer WITHOUT DAMAGING THE DISC? Or is my only option to schedule a Genius appointment and have them remove it for me?

Comment: It is a mechanical issue, not software. In old days there used to be a very small hole next to the cd slot, and when pushing in it with toothpick the disk came out.

Comment: if no paper-clip slot [idk if slot-loading drives have one of those], then next would be [in order of 'damage'] bent piece of card, tweezers or bent paper-clip

Comment: Indeed, there is not a paperclip-sized pinhole anywhere. Guess my only option is to take it in to the store…